# retrieve 16 items of data per row from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is a complicated one to explain so I think an example will be the best way to do this.

I have a simple table that stores two fields that contain times and one field that contains a date. I am making a view that will display date records with a maximum of 16 time fields that reference that same date. If there are more than 16 times relating to a single date, this needs to create a new record and carry on.

For example:

```
|         Date         | InTime | OutTime |
-------------------------------------------
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 07:00  | 07:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 08:00  | 08:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 09:00  | 09:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 10:00  | 10:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 11:00  | 11:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 12:00  | 12:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 13:00  | 13:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 14:00  | 14:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 15:00  | 15:30   |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 16:00  | 16:30   |
```

I want this to be displayed as:

```
|         Date         | InTime01 | OutTime02 | InTime03 | OutTime04 | InTime05 | OutTime06 | InTime07 | OutTime08 | InTime09 | OutTime10 | InTime11 | OutTime12 | InTime13 | OutTime14 | InTime15 | OutTime16 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 07:00    | 07:30     | 08:00    | 08:30     | 09:00    | 09:30     | 10:00    | 10:30     | 11:00    | 11:30     | 12:00    | 12:30     | 13:00    | 13:30     | 14:00    | 14:30     |
| 2014-01-01 00:00:00  | 15:00    | 15:30     | 16:00    | 16:30     |
```

I cannot really show you what I have already tried because I simply do not know where to start. I thought of using something like a cross apply but I don't think that would work with creating new records for days that have more than 16 times.

Comment: A SQL query is not the place for your user-interface! Write a query to get the data you need, then, in your user-interface code, format it to display to the user. You will find this so much simpler.

Comment: It is not really for a user interface, it is to help compatibility between an old version of software and a new one. Other than re-writing about 50% of this application, this seems to be the best way to complete this task.

Comment: So at the point at which you fetch this data, wrap that code in another function which formats it as the calling code expects. Doing this in SQL will involve either 16 outer joins or getting to grips with `PIVOT`. Doing it in code will be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Log
    (
      Date DATE ,
      InTime TIME ,
      OutTime TIME
    )
DECLARE @time TIME = '00:00'
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0 

WHILE @Counter < 24
    BEGIN

        INSERT  INTO #Log
                ( Date, InTime, OutTime )
        VALUES  ( GETDATE(), @time, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @time) ),
                ( DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), @time, DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @time) )
        SELECT  @time = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @time)


        SELECT  @Counter += 1
    END;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY InTime ) - 1 ) / 16 [Row]
               FROM     #Log
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Date, [Row] ORDER BY InTime ) Ord
               FROM     cte
             ),
        CteIn
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( SELECT    Date ,
                                    InTime ,
                                    Row ,
                                    Ord
                          FROM      cte2
                        ) AS sourcetable PIVOT ( MIN(InTime) FOR Ord IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16] ) ) AS pivotTable
             ),
        CteOut
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( SELECT    Date ,
                                    OutTime ,
                                    Row ,
                                    Ord
                          FROM      cte2
                        ) AS sourcetable PIVOT ( MIN(OutTime) FOR Ord IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16] ) ) AS pivotTable
             )
    SELECT  CteIn.Date ,
            CteIn.Row ,
            CteIn.[1] ,
            CteOut.[1] ,
            CteIn.[2] ,
            CteOut.[2] ,
            CteIn.[3] ,
            CteOut.[3] ,
            CteIn.[4] ,
            CteOut.[4] ,
            CteIn.[5] ,
            CteOut.[5] ,
            CteIn.[6] ,
            CteOut.[6] ,
            CteIn.[7] ,
            CteOut.[7] ,
            CteIn.[8] ,
            CteOut.[8] ,
            CteIn.[9] ,
            CteOut.[9] ,
            CteIn.[10] ,
            CteOut.[10] ,
            CteIn.[11] ,
            CteOut.[11] ,
            CteIn.[12] ,
            CteOut.[12] ,
            CteIn.[13] ,
            CteOut.[13] ,
            CteIn.[14] ,
            CteOut.[14] ,
            CteIn.[15] ,
            CteOut.[15] ,
            CteIn.[16],
            CteOut.[16]
    FROM    CteIn
            INNER JOIN CteOut ON CteOut.Date = CteIn.Date
                                 AND CteOut.Row = CteIn.Row
DROP TABLE #Log
```

Comment: The expected result has 16 time in total: 8 in, 8 out

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question +1